# .net c# obfuscation stacktrace displays as origin

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I need to obfuscate 4 assemblies. I tried several programs. The obfuscation worked at least according to log messages from the programs. But to be sure that it worked, inside of my program I artificialy throwed exception and write down the stacktrace to log file.

But even after obfuscating the stacktrace dispalys original name of class and method and I am sure, that the class is included in obfuscation.

Shouldn't be the stacktrace after obfuscating write with renamed names? If so, where can be the problem?

Comment: Debug or Release mode? Any .PDB files around?

Comment: Release mode .pdb are present but I am just taking dll which are copied to installer afterwards